# Return results in MySQL LIKE Operators order

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get the results in the order that I've set my LIKE operators. First the rows containing the title raspberry, then apple and last pear. As for now it's just returning the rows in the order that I inserted them into the table.

Example:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE 
title LIKE 'raspberry' OR 
title LIKE 'apple' OR 
title LIKE 'pear'
```

Comment: If you are comparing to constants, `title in ('raspberry', 'apple', 'pear')` is simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `CASE`

```
SELECT 
  id 
FROM
  TABLE 
WHERE title LIKE 'raspberry' 
  OR title LIKE 'apple' 
  OR title LIKE 'pear' 
ORDER BY 
  CASE
    WHEN title LIKE 'raspberry' 
    THEN 1 
    WHEN title LIKE 'apple' 
    THEN 2 
    WHEN title LIKE 'pear' 
    THEN 3 
    ELSE 4 
  END
```

[**CASE Syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Comment: @downvoters care to explain whats wrong in the answer

Answer (score 3):

Use [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE title in ('raspberry','apple','pear')
ORDER BY field(title, 'raspberry','apple','pear')
```